# C++ opengl get new vertex position after glTranslatef

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, vector, translation

I have a plane in my 3d space and I want to move it somewhere else, so I use glTranslate to do so.

The planes vertex data is: (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (1,1,0) and (0,1,0).
I translate the object to the position of (2,0,0) through the use of glTranslatef(2.0, 0.0, 0.0).

After the translation the point data is unchanged so if I was to want to collide with my plane the visual position is not its actual position.

Is there a way to get the point data from the MODELVIEW_MATRIX or at least a way to find out what the new values are after the glTranslate?

Don't respond with just add 2.0 to the actual values to move it because what if I want to the use glRotate etc. I still want the points locations.

Comment: You *should* add 2.0 to the actual values. To rotate the object, use `glTranslate` to move the origin to the object, then `glTranslate` again to move it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to maintain your own transformation matrix, you can get the current modelview matrix with:

```
GLfloat mat[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mat);
```

You can then apply this matrix to your vertices with a standard matrix multiplication. Keep in mind that the matrix is arranged in column-major order. With an input vector `xIn`, the transformed vector `xOut` is:

```
xOut[0] = mat[0] * xIn[0] + mat[4] * xIn[1] + mat[8] * xIn[2] + mat[12];
xOut[1] = mat[1] * xIn[0] + mat[5] * xIn[1] + mat[9] * xIn[2] + mat[13];
xOut[2] = mat[2] * xIn[0] + mat[6] * xIn[1] + mat[10] * xIn[2] + mat[14];
```

Keeping track of the current transformation matrix in your own code is really a better approach, IMHO. Aside from eliminating `glGet()` calls, which can be harmful to performance, it gets you on a path to using modern OpenGL (Core Profile), where the matrix stack and all related calls do not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a matrix from your translation and rotation, so that you can use the matrix to transform the coordinates.
There're many libraries to help you create such matrix and transform coordinates.